# code igniter dynamic routing

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, routes

I am using code igniter.

What I want to do is,

if a page is visited that does not exist

> example.com/idontexist

Then I want to first check a database to see if `idontexist` is in the database.

If it is then I want to route the user to

> example.com/action/idontexist.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to extend the CI_Router class with your own in application/core/MY_Router.php and just copy the method _set_routing() in your class.
Your changes would go somewhere after routes.php file is included and set to $this->routes property, you can add your custom routes.

```
include(APPPATH.'config/routes'.EXT);
...
$this->routes = ( ! isset($route) OR ! is_array($route)) ? array() : $route;
unset($route);

//Get your custom routes:
$your_routes = $this->_get_custom_routes();
foreach($your_routes as $custom_route)
{
    $this->routes[$custom_route['your_regex_match']] = $custom_route['controller'].'/'.$custom_route['action'];
}
```

Of course you might not need this, but I hope it gives you some idea.
This way you can add custom routes and since you will have to fetch them from database, consider caching them for better speed.

Comment: now, when I try to load CI using `get_instance()` to load URLs from db, I get this error: `Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233`

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this gets asked every week.

Open up your `application/config/routes.php`, then add something like this:

```
$route['^(:any)'] = "my_controller/get_article/$1";
```

Please note that it will route everything to a controller called `action`. If you have other controllers then you should add a route for them too (preferably placed before this one).

// EDIT: Using this you can goto `http://your-site.com/secrets-of-internet-marketing` and it will call the `get_article` function in the `my_controller` controller, and pass `"secrets-of-internet-marketing"` as the first argument. Which can then process with something like this:

```
public function get_article($article_name) { 
    // something like this: 
    $article = $this->article_model->get_model_by_name($article_name);
    $this->load->view('article', $article);
}
```

Comment: Not quite what I am asking.

I don't want to have this powered by a static file.

The idea is that I can add an article to the database, and that then becomes a route, But I dont want to have /articles/acticle/whatever. Get my point?

Comment: You have to do that check inside your controller. This just routes the requests into your controller, and gives you access to the input. Just take the argument `$1` and then look up it in your database, then return that article.